# C++-like static variables inside a F# function

Tags: f#, closures, mutable, ref

Is there some analog in F#? Something like

```
let f () =
   let mutable static a = 0
   ...
```

?

Comment: Do you need an access to this variable from outside the function? What is it's 'static' modifier for?

Comment: @ Petr No. No external access. I know that it's not a "functional way". A function should be invoked only once, that's why I'm interested in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you desugar `let f () = ...` to `let f = fun () -> ...`, you can put the declaration of `a` inside of the definition of `f`, but before the beginning of the function. This will make the function close over `a` while keeping `a` local to `f`. The problem with this is that you may not close over mutable variables, so you'll need to use a ref instead:

```
let f =
    let a = ref 0
    fun () ->
        ....
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest analog is to put the let before the function:

```
let mutable static a = 0
let f () =
```

If you really wanted to hide the variable you could encase the entire thing in a parent module.

Otherwise, sequence expressions allow for remembering variables in functions, but are a pretty significant change.

Some other ideas - hide inside a class:

```
type t() = 
    static let mutable t =  1
    static member f() = 1
```

or a module

```
module  t = 
    let mutable private t =  1
    let f() = 1
```

in the module approach, f is visible, but t is not

Comment: A little bit more complicated than variant from sepp2k. Thank you for help.